# I can't find a Voodoo Demon

Tags: terraria

Is there any more I need to do to have a Voodoo Demon spawn? I haven't killed Skeletron yet, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're in the Underworld, Voodoo Demons have a chance to spawn. They are more rare than regular Demons, so it might take a while to encounter some.